# Mapreduce individual avro record length?

Tags: java, avro

I have a single avro file with 5 records. I know you can write a mapreduce job to iterate over each record, but is there a way within my java mapreduce job mapper to get the "length" of the avro in the file so that I can get:

```
1) the starting position of each record as they are processed.
2) the length of the record as it exists in the file, such that I can use java code to "seek" to the start of a specific avro record within the file (i.e. 4th record).
```

If this is impossible based on current Avro libraries, that is fine.

The use case is I want to be able to output a file that contains something like:

```
<Record Number> <StartIndex> <EndIndex>
Record1 0 150
Record2 151 270
...
```

Comment: What is the usecase? As you may already know avro is schema based and to read the records you would use the avro api in java and accordingly read the datum. So what are you trying to do

Comment: [How to get start end and end of each avro record in a compressed avro file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528644/how-to-get-start-end-and-end-of-each-avro-record-in-a-compressed-avro-file) appears to be quite close to your question